# EF6 many-to-many mapping of more than two entities and composite keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, many-to-many, seed

I have these classes:

```
public class Behandler
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Treatment> Treatments { get; set; }
    // And other fields
}

public class Profession
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Behandler> Behandlers { get; set; }
    // And other fields
}

public class Treatment
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Behandler> Behandlers { get; set; }
    // And other fields
}
```

I need many-to-many mappings between Behandler/Profession and Behandler/Treatment, but Behandler has composite keys and Treatment does too, with the added complexity that one of the keys contained in the composite key of Treatment is the primary key of Profession. So I need a many-to-many mapping between Behandler/Treatment and Behandler/Profession, as well as a many-to-one mapping between Treatment/Profession.

I tried creating join tables and classes, but I always get Primary/Foreignkey exceptions in my seed method. I also tried various techniques using fluent api, but I cannot seem to get the right database structure or I am adding data incorrectly to the database. Does someone have an idea how to map this correctly or if I can create a simpler setup?

Comment: Any reason to not use Id fields?

Comment: @ben Because I need the fields that I assigned as keys to be distinct

Comment: I would recommend using a unique constraint for that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/unique-constraints

Comment: @Ben Won't I end up with the same problem? (EF telling me the name for Profession already exist) ?

Comment: @Ben Btw. I'm using EF6, not Core.